# What are the prerequisites to join a flight School ? Is it different for each country?

Tags: flight-school

(I didn't finish Highschool, failed French and math fml)

I've finished my 3 year diploma in Architecture.
I'm 23. Nobody has ever supported me and my dream to be a pilot. Not even my parents, heck they even found it funny, that I could even dream that.

But I'm not gonna stop till I drop. 
I just wanna know if flight schools need a student to be a highschool graduate. Cause I've only got GCSEs no A levels. 
  I have 6 GCSEs with physics chemistry and math being 3 of them, and C grade on most. Does that help?

Comment: What kind of pilot do you want to be?

Comment: No highschool needed.  No degree of any kind.  Just money.  Now, an employer may want to see a diploma or degree.  I never cared if an applicant had one though (charter, not airline).

Comment: You may add your current state of research (have you already contacted schools? Do you know names of some schools? Any other relevant elements)

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think you can manage the exams for flight school if you can't even pass a high school exam?

They're at at least the same level of complexity...

But no, in general you don't need a minimum education level to start flight training. That said, if you want to get hired as a commercial pilot at some point, many employers WILL have education requirements without which they won't give you a job.

This is for EASA requirements, which are in use in the UK where you seem to be located. And of course individual flight schools may well decide to not take on people they expect to not have the capability to pass the exams, as having a high rate of failure on exams may reflect poorly on them. But that's not a legal requirement and would be a policy of the specific company in question.

Comment: It should also be noted that professional pilot training isn't "take it till you make it",  failures during training can be grounds for being rejected from any future jobs, or may restrict the applicant to cargo ops or small aircraft.